# What does pub.package mean

Tags: sql, dynamic-sql

I have a dynamic SQL select statement that selects various fields from something named `pub.package.customer`.

I have never seen this before and I don't what it means or where it is getting the data from.  If anyone has seen this or something similar before you knowledge would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Depends on where and how it is used.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

pub.package.customer

- pub is database name
- package is schema name
- customer is table name

The full path of object is dot delimited name

```
 Servername.Databasename.Ownername.Objectname
```

Here your object is customer table from which various fields are being used in your dynamic sql query.

Comment: Or schema.table.column, or table.column.method.

Comment: yes correct ..in question it is mentioned fields are being selected from pub.package.customer so i assumed it is Servername.Databasename.Ownername

Comment: Correct. I missed that part. (However, I'm not fully comfortable with the method invocation syntax. The syntax itself can't distinguish between schema.table.column and table.column.method... Poor ANSI decision...)

Comment: This answer is specific to SQL Server, not a general "SQL" answer (in standard SQL there is only  `catalog.schema.object`). In Oracle `pub.package.customer` _could_ also mean a schema named `pub` a package named `package` and a procedure named `customer`